# Total number of permutations of zeros and ones

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different ways you can arrange zeros and ones such that the total number of ones before any point in the sequence is greater than or equal to the number of zeros before that point. This can also be interpreted like this, how many different ways you can arrange zeros and ones in a sequence such that the sum till whatever point you take in the sequence is non negative. There are **2n** ones and zeros. For example consider this sequence of 6 ones and zeros,

111000, 110100, 101010, 111111, 111110 are all permutations that we are looking for. But 011100, 100110, 000000 are permutations that we are not interested in as there is at least one point in the sequence before which the sum is non positive.

Thanks in advance;)

Comment: Do you always want to end up with the same number of zeros and ones?

Comment: No, my bad. I didn't mention it, sorry.

Comment: These are the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out:)

Comment: To be clear:  The Catalan Numbers assume that the number of zeroes and ones is the same.  That appears to be different that what you want (though your use of "permutations" is confusing.  What set are you permuting?)

Comment: There are many questions on the site about Catalan numbers.  The one I picked is not a perfect duplicate.  The Wikipedia page is a good place to start.

Comment: For the problem where all you require is that the number of $1's$ be greater than or equal to the number of $0's$ see the discussion surrounding [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).